# Como puedo crear un objeto con lodash a partir de otro?

Tags: javascript, typescript

disculpen la pregunta si es muy novata pero me leí la documentación y por mas que intente no logre sacar lo que quiero.

Tengo el siguiente objeto

```
[
[ " 2018-12-01 " , " AM " , " ID123 " , 5000 ],
[ " 2018-12-01 " , " AM " , " ID545 " , 7000 ],
[ " 2018-12-01 " , " PM " , " ID545 " , 3000 ],
[ " 2018-12-02 " , " AM " , " ID545 " , 7000 ]
]
```

y quiero con lodash llegar a tener el siguiente objeto

```
{
" 2018-12-01 " : {
" AM " : 12000 ,
" PM " : 3000
},
" 2018-12-02 " : {
" AM " : 7000 ,
}
}
```

agradezco la ayuda, he intentado con esto

```
const nuevoObj = _(this.lista)
      .groupBy([' 2018-12-01 ', ' 2018-12-02 '])
      .map((value, key) => ({
        ' 2018-12-01 ': _.groupBy(_.filter(value, function(x) {
          return x[0] === ' 2018-12-01 ';
        }), ['AM']),
        ' 2018-12-02 ': _.filter(value, function(x) {
          return x[0] === ' 2018-12-02 ';
        })
      }))
      .value();
```

pero no logro agrupar lo demás, y poco conozco lodash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de hacerlo(aunque no necesitas hacer uso de lodash) es iterando sobre el array y creando un objeto nuevo. Preguntando por los indices ya creados, por último sumando los valores, de esta forma:

```js
let initial = [
    [ " 2018-12-01 " , " AM " , " ID123 " , 5000 ],
    [ " 2018-12-01 " , " AM " , " ID545 " , 7000 ],
    [ " 2018-12-01 " , " PM " , " ID545 " , 3000 ],
    [ " 2018-12-02 " , " AM " , " ID545 " , 7000 ]
];
let final = {}; // creas tu objeto contendor
let day = '';
let time = '';
initial.forEach(el => {
    day = el[0];
    time = el[1];
    if (typeof final[day] === 'undefined') { // preguntas si ya existe
        final[day] = {};
    }
    if (typeof final[day][time] === 'undefined') { // preguntas si AM y PM ya estan en el objeto
        final[day][time] = 0;
    }
    final[day][time] += el[3]; // sumas el valor para obtener el resultado
});

console.log(final);
```

De esta manera obtienes los elementos como los necesitas.

Comment: Hola anibal, quería hacerlo con lodash ya que es la libreria que estamos usando y de paso quería aprender mas, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, intentare hacerlo como dices y te cuento.

Comment: Ok, Me comentas.